# Injecting custom network url not working relayjs

Tags: relayjs

I am following this sample app : https://github.com/relayjs/relay-starter-kit

```js
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('http://localhost:8080/graphql')
);
```

with custom url i am getting following errors

> OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/graphql
>   net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSEself.fetch @ relay.js:21558Promise @
>   app.js:3335self.fetch @ relay.js:21508sendTimedRequest @
>   relay.js:20131module.exports @ relay.js:20186tryCallTwo @
>   relay.js:3762doResolve @ relay.js:3879Promise @
>   relay.js:3782fetchWithRetries @ relay.js:20122_sendQuery @
>   relay.js:13042(anonymous function) @ relay.js:12976sendQueries @
>   relay.js:12975sendQueries @ relay.js:3502processQueue @
>   relay.js:17591(anonymous function) @ relay.js:17582tryCallOne @
>   relay.js:3754(anonymous function) @ relay.js:3820flush @ relay.js:9457
>   relay.js:21558 OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/graphql
>   net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSEself.fetch @ relay.js:21558Promise @
>   app.js:3335self.fetch @ relay.js:21508sendTimedRequest @
>   relay.js:20131 relay.js:21558 OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/graphql
>   net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSEself.fetch @ relay.js:21558Promise @
>   app.js:3335self.fetch @ relay.js:21508sendTimedRequest @
>   relay.js:20131 relay.js:7449 Network request failed_markAsRejected @
>   relay.js:7449_handleSubtractedQueryFailure @ relay.js:7430tryCallOne @
>   relay.js:3754(anonymous function) @ relay.js:3820flush @ relay.js:9457

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that your application is running on port 3000. If you try to make client=>server requests to a different domain/port combination, without enabling such cross-origin requests on the server side, your browser will use its default [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) policies to block the request.

You can enable requests from all origins, on the server side, like this:

```js
import cors from 'cors';

var graphQLServer = express();
graphQLServer.use(cors());
/* ... */
```

Check out the [cors docs](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enable-cors-for-a-single-route) for more fine grained control.

Be sure to `npm install --save cors`, wherever your server code lives.

Comment: thank you :) , didn't know  about different ports communication comes under cros.